# MKPlacemark() creating retain cycle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, state

I have a @State property that's initialized with a struct I created (Landmark) that takes in a MKPlacemark.

```
@State private var selectedLandmark: Landmark = Landmark(placemark: MKPlacemark())
```

Here's the code for the struct:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

struct Landmark {

let placemark: MKPlacemark

var id: UUID {
    UUID()
}

var name: String {
    placemark.name ?? ""
}

var title: String {
    placemark.title ?? ""
}

var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    placemark.coordinate
}
}
```

Whenever there are any updates to any state/binding vars within this view, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and no logs. If I remove the reference to MKPlacemark, everything works fine. Is this possibly a case of a strong reference being retained somewhere?

Steps to reproduce:

Create a "child" view:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MKPlaceChild: View {
    @Binding var showCreateEvent: Bool
    @State private var selectedLandmark: Landmark = Landmark(placemark: MKPlacemark())

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        
        Button("Cancel") {
            self.showCreateEvent = false
        }
    }
}
}
```

Create a parent view:

```
struct MKPlaceParent: View {
    @State var showCreateEvent: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showCreateEvent {
                MKPlaceChild(showCreateEvent: $showCreateEvent)
            } else {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you tap on "Cancel" button, an error occurs :(
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is all very interesting but what do you imagine it has to do with a "retain cycle"?

Comment: Honestly, at this point, I'm not sure anymore. My initial gut feeling was that MKPlacemark was creating strong references to each property inside Landmark but I'm not completely certain that can happen

Comment: As an aside, but you surely don't want this to be a computed property: `var id: UUID { UUID() }`. Perhaps `let id = UUID()`, so it's initialized once and only once. But with a computed property, you're going to get a unique `id` every time you reference it.

Comment: Nice catch, Rob. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in wrong initialiser. Here is fixed part (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
struct MKPlaceChild: View {
    @Binding var showCreateEvent: Bool
    @State private var selectedLandmark: Landmark = Landmark(placemark: 
          MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D()))      // << here !!
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why that would make a difference and what the error could've been?